# What is wrong with this AJAX / JSP code?

Tags: java, jquery, css, ajax, jsp

When I click the search button for the first two times it doesn't show anything. Then clicking again it shows the results for the first search, so basically the results are delayed by 2 'search' clicks.

The tables are only flashed and don't stay visible. Why?

```
/*this is the code for the servlet*/

case "/ViewArchive":
    String line = "";
    searchString = request.getParameter("searchString");
    searchBy = request.getParameter("searchBy");
    searchType = request.getParameter("searchType");
    if(searchString.isEmpty()==false)
    {
        if(searchType.equalsIgnoreCase("major incident"))
        {
            mi = new DBManager().getArchiveMajorIncident(searchString, searchBy);                                      
            request.getSession().setAttribute("majorincident", mi);
        }
        else if(searchType.equalsIgnoreCase("elevated ticket"))
        {
            et = new DBManager().getArchiveElevatedTicket(searchString, searchBy);                                  
            request.getSession().setAttribute("elevatedticket", et);
                            }
        }
        else if(searchType.equalsIgnoreCase("open critical/high issue"))
        {
            oh = new DBManager().getArchiveOpenCriticalHighIssue(searchString, searchBy);                                   
            request.getSession().setAttribute("opencriticalhighissue", oh);
        }
    }

/*
request.getSession().removeAttribute("searchType");
request.getSession().setAttribute("searchType",searchType);
request.getRequestDispatcher("viewhistory.jsp").forward(request, response);
*/
```

```
**JSP PAGE**

<div class="center">
    <div class="search">
    <form>
        Search: 
        <input id="searchString" type="text"  name="searchString" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Type: 
        <select name="searchType" id="searchType">
            <option>Major Incident</option>
            <option>Elevated Ticket</option>
            <option>Open Critical/High Issues</option>            
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

       By: 
       <select name="searchBy" id="searchBy">
           <option>EM No.</option>
           <option>IM No.</option>
       </select>

       <button class="myButton searchBtn" id="searchBtn" type="submit" value="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    </div>

   <h3 style="display:none"></h3>
   <table style ="display:none" id = "MajorIncidentsTable" width="100%">
       <colgroup> 
           <col style="width:8%">
           <col style="width:11%">
           <col style="width:20%">
           <col style="width:8%">
           <col style="width:20%">
           <col style="width:10%">
           <col style="width:10%">
           <col style="width:11%">
       </colgroup>  
       <tr>  
           <th>EM#</th>
           <th>Date Opened</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Current Status</th>
           <th>Next Action Step/s</th>
           <th>Technical Owner</th>
           <th>Ownership</th>
           <th>Checkpoint Schedule</th>
       </tr>
       <tbody>
       <c:forEach var="c" items="${majorincident}" varStatus="counter">
            <tr>
                <td>${c.em_no}</td>
                <td>${c.dateopened}</td>
                <td>${c.description}</td>
                <td>${c.current_status}</td>
                <td>${c.next_action_steps}</td>
                <td>${c.technical_ownership}</td>
                <td>${c.owners}</td>
                <td>${c.checkpoint_schedule}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

```
/* This is in the JSP page too */

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* if(
               $majorincident != null 
               || $elevatedticket != null 
               || $opencriticalhighissue != null){

        } */

        $("#searchBtn").click(function(){
            var name = $("#searchString").val();
            var type = $("#searchType>option:selected").text();
            var by = $("#searchBy>option:selected").text();

            if(type=="Major Incident"){
                $("h3").css('display', 'block');
                $("#MajorIncidentsTable").css('display', 'block');
                $("#ElevatedTicketsTable").css('display', 'none');
                $("#OpenCriticalHighIssuesTable").css('display', 'none');
                $('h3').replaceWith(type);
            }
            else if(type=="Elevated Ticket"){
                $("h3").css('display', 'block');
                $("#MajorIncidentsTable").css('display', 'none');
                $("#ElevatedTicketsTable").css('display', 'block');
                $("#OpenCriticalHighIssuesTable").css('display', 'none');
                $('h3').replaceWith(type);
            }
            else if(type=="Open Critical/High Issues"){
                $("h3").css('display', 'block');
                $("#MajorIncidentsTable").css('display', 'none');
                $("#ElevatedTicketsTable").css('display', 'none');
                $("#OpenCriticalHighIssuesTable").css('display', 'block');
                $('h3').replaceWith(type);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url : "ViewArchive",
                data : {"searchString" : name.toString(), "searchType" : type,"searchBy":by },
                type : "POST",
                success : function(msg) {
                }
            });

            name = "";
            type = "";
            by = "";    
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Don't post your whole code, just add relevant code part.

Comment: can you do debug in your javascript code?

Comment: @AkashChavda im sorry what do you mean by that

Comment: you can check https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging link, this link is specify to how javascript debug work in chrome.

Comment: may be you need to wait some time to get the response, because just you might have delays.